# How to initialize `LocalizationResourceManager`

Tags: xamarin.forms

I found the [LocalizationResourceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/helpers/localizationresourcemanager) class. It enables users to respond to culture changes at runtime. But I found that it need to initialize with just one ResourceManager `LocalizationResourceManager.Current.Init(AppResources.ResourceManager);`. It doesn't make sense.

In my app, there're many pages and I also create many resx files for the specific page. For example,

-- Resx

----Main

--------MainResource.resx

--------MainResource.en-US.resx

--------MainResource.es.resx

--------MainResource.ja.resx

----Setting

--------SettingResource.resx

--------SettingResource.en-US.resx

--------SettingResource.ja.resx

......

In this case, How to initialize `LocalizationResourceManager`?

Comment: [localize-text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows#localize-text-in-xamarinforms)

Comment: most apps use a single resource file, not one per page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `AppResources`  represents your resource file , modify your code as below

```
LocalizationResourceManager.Current.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => MainResource.Culture = LocalizationResourceManager.Current.CurrentCulture;
LocalizationResourceManager.Current.Init(MainResource.ResourceManager);
LocalizationResourceManager.Current.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
```

Check official sample :

[image]

https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/tree/main/samples .